# How to enforce a constraint over multiple tables?

Tags: constraint, erd

I have the following five tables:

- PRODUCT
- FEATURE
- PROVIDER
- PROVIDER_PRODUCT
- PROVIDER_FEATURE

The logic is as follows:

A generic `PRODUCT` can have one or more `FEATURE`s. There are different `PROVIDER`s who are delivering the same product, but with different details, and the same `FEATURE`s, also with different details.

The problem is that with this ERD I can create a `PRODUCT` p1 with `FEATURE` f1 and a `PRODUCT` p2 with `FEATURE` f2. Then I create `PROVIDER` pv1. Now I can create a `PROVIDER_PRODUCT` pvp1 with `PROVIDER` pv1 and `PRODUCT` p1. But when I create a `PROVIDER_FEATURE` pvp1 I should only be allowed to add `FEATURE` f1, as this is the `FEATURE` that is linked to p1 via the `PROVIDER_PRODUCT` table. However I can also add a `FEATURE` f2.

How can I create a constraint that prevents the user from entering a `PROVIDER_FEATURE` that is part of a `FEATURE` that is part of a `PRODUCT` but that is not the `PRODUCT` on the `PROVIDER_PRODUCT` that is on that `PROVIDER_FEATURE`? Do I need to solve that in a stored procedure, or is there a more elegant way to enforce this?

```
+-------------------+       +--------------------+
|                   |       |                    |
| PRODUCT           +-----> | FEATURE            |
|                   |       |                    |
+---------+---------+       +----------+---------+
          |                            |          
          |                            |          
          v                            v          

+-------------------+       +--------------------+
|                   |       |                    |
| PROVIDER_PRODUCT  +-----> | PROVIDER_FEATURE   |
|                   |       |                    |
+-------------------+       +--------------------+

          ^                                       
          |                                       
          |                                       
+---------+---------+                             
|                   |                             
| PROVIDER          |                             
|                   |                             
+-------------------+
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `PROVIDER_FEATURE`? Can't you derive this information via the other tables, or are there additional attributes involved?

Comment: Assuming you really need this table, in theory you can have a check constraint with a sub-select. Not many DBMS support this though. Another common way to enforce a rule like yours is to use triggers.

Comment: @Lennart No therre are additional attributes involved.

Comment: Then `PROVIDER_FEATURE` can be expressed as a view. Something like: `CREATE VIEW  PROVIDER_FEATURE AS select <product_key>, <feature_key> from PROVIDER_PRODUCT join PRODUCT on ... join FEATURE on ...`.

Comment: Sorry, I said there ARE additional attributes involved. And not every product - feature combination is also a provider_product - provider_feature combination. Features can be on the generic product that are not on the provider_product

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread that. Funny thing is when I read it fast once again I see "There are no ..." :-) Then I believe @Todd Everett's solution is the way to go. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can easily be done by using cascading keys that overlap.  Here is an example using the Oracle Data Modeler (note there is a bug in this tool or a configuration issue as the Provider_Feature table should show each column as PF meaning both PK and FK):

[image]

In this example, the PK to Provider Product includes the Product Number provided, and the PK to Feature includes the Feature Number supported for that Product.  The Product Number in Provider_Feature is a FK back to both the Provider Product and the Feature.  The FK constraints thus prevent inserting a Provider Feature for a Product Feature combination not already instantiated as a Product Feature possibility.

This solution assumes that a feature is identified by a Product - that is a feature cannot exist outside the context of a product.  That assumption is likely valid as features, in and of them selves, have no meaning with the context of a product.  However, if you do want to instantiate features that can included on multiple products, then you simply add a Feature table and make the current Feature table a Product_Feature table.

Often database designers assume each table must have its own "identifier."  Nothing could be further from the truth.  Please see [Fabian Pascal's excellent blog post](http://www.dbdebunk.com/2015/08/surrogate-key-illusions.html) on this topic.  Adding a surrogate Key to each table means the natural business rule you are trying to enforce can no longer be enforced declaratively via PK and FK constraints, just as you have found.  If you must have a SK for some reason your only option is to enforce the constraint **procedurally** using a trigger. This option is **much** more problematic.  First, you have to write, debug, test and maintain the trigger.  The book [Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590597451) provides excellent detail on how difficult it can turn out to be to express constraints using procedural logic in a way that performs adequately.  Secondly, triggers in and of them selves **can sometimes** be performance inhibitors as they execute serially.

My recommendation is to use the natural declarative approach.

Comment: Hi Todd. You said, "The Product Number in Provider_Feature is a FK back to both the Provider Product and the Feature." Are you saying there is a foreign key to the `Product Number` column in `Provider_Feature` from both `Product Number` columns in `Provider_Product` and `Feature` tables? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible.  The syntax is to declare 2 foreign key constraints in the product feature table.  The first looks something like  CONSTRAINT [name] FOREIGN KEY (Provider Number, Product Number) REFERENCES Provider_Product (Provider Number, Product Number).  The second looks something like CONSTRAINT [name] FOREIGN KEY (Product Number, Feature Number) REFERENCES Feature (Product Number, Feature Number).  The Oracle data modeler which I used to create the example will generate this DDL using what it calls "folded" keys.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I guess my SQL is rusty because I forgot foreign key constraints can be used like that. I tested it out in a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d94c40) to be sure (the Oracle fiddle tool seems to be broken, but your design works in MySQL). If I got anything wrong in the fiddle, let me know and I'll correct it for posterity.